# IP2 1dB compression point representation and formula

Tags: matlab, distortion, non-linear, compression, intermodulation-products

I'm trying to calculate the 1dB compression point in a second order interception. I did find many examples using third order, however, for a second order, I couldn't find much.

In Matlab I could find the interception point using the following code:

```
% Parameters
a1=5; a2=4;
G1=20*log10(a1);G2=10*log10(a2^2/2);

% Equations
Pi=-10:0.1:10;
Po=G1+Pi;
P2=G2+2*Pi;

% Interception Point (3)
IPi=(G1-G2);
IPo=G1+IPi;
```

How can I get the 1dB compression point (referenced to output) using this code? And the representation of the gain.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This question is in risk of being closed because you show little research effort and for being unclear what are you asking. A quick google search yields this: http://rfic.eecs.berkeley.edu/~niknejad/ee142_fa05lects/pdf/lect9.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I also found that powerpoint. Still doesn't answer my question

Comment: May I ask why not?

Comment: From the slides I get IIP2=a1/a2. this is the interception point referenced to the input. I guess in my case 5/4. right? How about the 1dB compression point (referenced to the output)?

Comment: It seems you're looking for a "straight" answer as in some Matlab code. You will not get such an answer here. Do you understand what a 1dB compression point **means** or an IP3 point ? Do you understand what that included Matlab code does ? Why do you need output referred 1dB cp ? If you knew input referred 1dB cp, how would you determine output 1dB cp ? (It's not a difficult calculation).

Comment: I'm looking for straight answer. If you want to help, indicate books and other useful resources. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the straight answer you're looking for:

**You can't calculate \$P_{-1dB}\$ from \$IP_2\$.**

Why? Because \$IP_2\$ doesn't contain any information about the cubic term of the non-linearity (\$a_3\$), as it only depends on the linear (\$a_1\$) and quadratic terms (\$a_2\$). Recall that:

$$
s_o(t)=a_1s_i(t)+a_2s_i^2(t)+a_3s_i^3(t)
$$

For a single-tone input \$s_i(t)=A_0cos(\omega_0t)\$ where \$\omega_0=2{\pi}f_0\$, this is what you get at the output:

$$
\begin{align}
s_o(t)&=s_{o,\ DC}(t)+s_{o,\ f_0}(t)+s_{o,\ 2f_0}(t)+s_{o,\ 3f_0}(t)\\
\text{where:}\\
s_{o,\ DC}(t)&=\frac{1}{2}a_2A_0^2\\
s_{o,\ f_0}(t)&=\left(1+\frac{3}{4}\frac{a_3}{a_1}A_0\right)a_1A_0cos(\omega_0t)\\
s_{o,\ 2f_0}(t)&= \frac{1}{2}a_2A_0^2cos(2\omega_0t)\\
s_{o,\ 3f_0}(t)&=\frac{1}{4}a_3A_0^3cos(3\omega_0t)
\end{align}
$$

The gain compression is a consequence of the cubic term (more generally speaking: of the odd-order terms). That's why you can calculate \$P_{-1dB}\$ from \$IP_3\$: because it contains information about \$a_3\$ (and about \$a_1\$, as well), but not from \$IP_2\$:

$$
\begin{align}
IP_{i,2}&=\frac{a_1}{a_2}\\
IP_{i,3}&=\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}\left\lvert\frac{a_1}{a_3}\right\rvert}\\
\end{align}
$$

Also note that your Matlab code doesn't even consider the cubic term:

```
% Parameters
a1=5; a2=4;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, it's not a "straight" answer. It's a well defined explanation which I thank you. I wasn't looking for a straight answer (I REPEAT). This explanation is more than useful.

Comment: You're welcome. If it's been useful for you, I'm more than happy.

Answer (score 0):

There are famous diagrams for IP2 and IP3; this diagram represents IP2.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0bffM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>